# Pusher cluster autodetect

Tags: cluster-computing, pusher

I wanted to know, why there is no auto-detection of the the clients position (using the IP) to match the right pusher-cluster? (I am totally no expert in this field but I think this should be an easy way to detect the best cluster). I am planing to use pusher for my gaming app, since it’s worldwide it would be great if the cluster matching works automatically.

https://pusher.com

Comment: https://pusher.com/docs/clusters

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible.

You *could* use an API like [GEOIPS](https://www.geoips.com/en/developer/api-guide) to get the continent from the IP address, and then map this to the nearest of the three Pusher clusters.

The problem with this approach is that Pusher apps are tied to a specific region. If you are having clients connect to each region, then you would have to create an app per region, and publish events to all three.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to use a e.g. the default "us-east-1" cluster for all clients worldwide? The latency wouldn't be a problem for my purpose.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `us-east-1` is already the default cluster that clients connect to.

Comment: I just wonder if the us-east-1 cluster works everywhere, regardless of the region where the client goes online. The us-east-1 works in Europe this is what i tested. But does it also work in Asia or Australia?